# Conditional code inserting extra line breaks when it evaluates to False

Tags: xslt, bi-publisher

I have the following PeopleSoft BI Publisher RTF template with some conditional code for Sign-On Bonus  that will only display the text block conditionally.

[image]

If the Sign-on bonus condition is true and the paragraph displays, the spacing between the Sign-on bonus paragraph and the Benefits paragraph is how I want it to be (double spaced) as shown here:

[image]

However when the condition for the Sign-on bonus is False (does not display paragraph) then there is a larger space (line breaks) between the Overtime paragraph and the Benefits paragraph. Is there a way to prevent this from occuring? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Here is a side by side comparison:

[image]

Comment: What does this have to do with the XSLT tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the new-line at the end of the paragraph, which you want in the conditional section, within the if-statement rather than outside of it.